# How to leave from group chat using node-xmpp

Tags: node.js, xmpp, openfire, xmppframework, node-xmpp

[This](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#exit) doesn't work. Here `cl` is xmpp-client object of who wants to leave from group.

```
cl.on('online', function (userData) {
    var userJid = userData.jid.user + '@' + userData.jid.domain + "/" + userData.jid.resource,
    roomJid = params.typeId + params.service + userData.jid.domain + '/' + params.userName;
    pres = new xmpp.Element('presence', {
        from : userJid,
        to   : roomJid,  //54d213e000e9e50c4e8e5a2b@conference.domain/nickName
        type : 'unavailable',
        xmlns : 'jabber:client'
    });
    status = cl.send(pres);
});
```